# Copy all shared objects from ldd output

Tags: linux, copy, shared-objects, ldd

How can I copy all shared objects from `ldd` output of my executable?

I'm looking for something like this, but this is for `find` and I need for `ldd`:

```
find -name "*python3.7*" -exec cp "{}" /home/user/python/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ \;
```

EDIT:

Example of `ldd` output:

```
adrian@adrian:~/Dokumenty/PracaMagisterska/eclipse/0_FULL_GAME$ ldd 0_FULL_GAME
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcc15fc000)
    libsfml-window.so.2.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsfml-window.so.2.5 (0x00007ff1f8d57000)
    libpython3.8.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0 (0x00007ff1f8809000)
    libsfml-system.so.2.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsfml-system.so.2.5 (0x00007ff1f87fb000)
    libsfml-graphics.so.2.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsfml-graphics.so.2.5 (0x00007ff1f87a3000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ff1f85c2000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff1f8473000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ff1f8456000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff1f8264000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007ff1f8127000)
    libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007ff1f811a000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007ff1f8092000)
    libudev.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 (0x00007ff1f8066000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007ff1f8036000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007ff1f801a000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff1f7ff7000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff1f7ff1000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007ff1f7fec000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007ff1f7f2d000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff1f8e00000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007ff1f7f01000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007ff1f7eec000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007ff1f7ce2000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007ff1f7c2a000)
    libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007ff1f7bf6000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007ff1f7bbc000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007ff1f7bb6000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007ff1f7bae000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007ff1f7b94000)
```

Comment: Can you post an example of your `ldd` output?  copying might work by selecting lines with `awk` and using built-in system() or pipe to `xargs`

Comment: I'm not familiar with `awk` and `xargs`. I thought about split output (I don't now how), use `grep` and apply this to `find` version

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The example `ldd` output above was saved to "infile". Description: run `awk` to select lines with 4 fields and `echo` a command that would copy the lib from the third field to a destination directory:

```
awk 'NF == 4 { system("echo cp " $3 " destdir") }' infile
```

Instead of reading from infile, could pipe the output from `ldd` into `awk`, eg:

```
ldd 0_FULL_GAME | awk 'NF == 4 { system("echo cp " $3 " destdir") }'
```

Replace destdir with your directory of choice. Once the displayed commands look OK, remove the `echo` to actually copy, eg:

```
ldd 0_FULL_GAME | awk 'NF == 4 { system("cp " $3 " chosen-dir") }'
```

Comment: Good stuff... Note 1: it won't include anything that is dynamically loaded (e.g. `dlopen`) by the process.  Note 2: add to `cp` the option `--parents` to keep the directory hierarchy