Shared library locations from executable, to copy for Docker multi-stage build
ldd is a partial solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63663617
I am trying to build a small Docker image from a large one. So I build my Rust project and COPY --from=stage0 into my distroless (also tried FROM scratch). Which gives me a bunch of errors indicating missing shared libraries.
How do I automatically copy over all the necessary libraries?

See if you can statically link your program, so the libraries are included in the executable.

Yeah I tried that but ran into a bunch of PostgreSQL errors. The same errors this guy gets - https://github.com/utdemir/ghc-musl/issues/15#issuecomment-890354748 - was trying to build on alpine with musl

Also came across this https://github.com/Kybernado/DepCopy but it is rather basic (and doesn't support sh)


Use ldd to find the library files
Copy all libraries into one folder
COPY them in the second stage of the multistage build
Ensure the destination is in the default library search path
Win


Can you [edit] this answer to include some more details?  How do you get from the output of ldd to a list of files to copy, for example?

That's what the linked answer does. Still not supremely happy with my solution so hoping for alternative answers, e.g., ones which find dlopen calls and copy those libraries over also + recursively go through the libraries to ensure all their interdependant libraries are copied over also.
